# git pull --rebase upstream master pollutes my Github PR diff

Tags: git, github, open-source

Before I make a change to my PR, as requested by the maintainers, I do a `git pull --rebase upstream master` to place my commits on top of other new commits in the code base.

However, this seems to [pollute the diff of my PR](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/20709/files) with changes from other commits.

Why is this happening?
Since the base of my PR is `upstream/master`, and I have just `git pull --rebase upstream master`, shouldn't the diff only show my code?

Answer (score 1):

I do this all the time and have found the following process the best way to solve it:

Write down the git commit hashes for all commits in the PR that you want to save (i.e. your commits).

Then run the following:

```
git fetch upstream
git reset --hard upstream/master
git cherry-pick <hash 1>
git cherry-pick <hash 2>
// cherry-pick all of your commits then:
git push -f origin your-branch
```

And it should fix your PR automatically

Answer (score 0):

After updating from `upstream` you should update your `origin`:

```
git push origin upstream/master:master
```

and then update your PR.

Comment: To clarify, my PR originates from my feature branch `origin/my-feature`, not my `origin/master`. So why does updating `origin/master` matter for the PR?

Comment: Because only `master` is mentioned in the question. If you've updated a different branch from `upstream` you should update it at `origin`.