# Accidentally added other's commits to my PR using git rebase

Tags: git, github

I was going to do more work on a feature and before coding i ran `git pull --rebase upstream master`. Then ran `git push origin feature-branch`; this resulted in one of those 'fast-forward' errors in which I then ran `git pull origin feature-branch`. Following that I fixed a merge conflict and ran `git push origin feature-branch` again. Now my pr from `feature-branch` to `master` is polluted with other's commits. I noticed this questions was asked previously but never [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49969437/git-pull-rebase-upstream-master-pollutes-my-github-pr-diff).

Can someone explain what I did wrong and maybe how to fix it?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I figured it out:

Write down the git commit hashes for all commits in the PR that you want to save (i.e. your commits).

Then run the following:

```
git fetch upstream
git reset --hard upstream/master
git cherry-pick <hash 1>
git cherry-pick <hash 2>
// cherry-pick all of your commits then:
git push -f origin your-branch
```

And it should fix your PR automatically

Comment: Should the cherry-pick commands be run in order of oldest to newest commits?

Comment: This seems rather cumbersome compared to rebasing and dropping, as proposed by Rory O'Kane.

Answer (score 5):

If your current branch has commits you want to keep (your own) mixed in with commits you don't want (the ones added by the rebase), you can use `git rebase --interactive` to edit your branch again and keep only the commits you pick.

First, find the hash of the commit *before* the last one you might want to edit. If your branch was originally based on `master`, a good commit to choose is the one returned by `git merge-base HEAD master`.

Next, start an interactive rebase from the current commit to that old commit:

```
git rebase --interactive f1c3d284
```

Your text editor will pop up with lines representing each commit in your branch and with instructions from Git below them. As the instructions say, change `pick` to `drop` for each line representing a commit you don't want. When you save and close the document, your current branch will be rebuilt according to those instructions.