# Why rebase add other's commit to my pr in GitHub

Tags: git, rebase

I have searched for similar question like [Accidentally added other's commits to my PR using git rebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50780902/accidentally-added-others-commits-to-my-pr-using-git-rebase). The answer for that just provide a method to remove unwanted commit from pr, but I still don't know why this happen.

These are commands to reproduce my problem, but I'm not sure for others.

```bash
>>> (main) git log --oneline --graph -5
* fa9a315 
* e52240c
* 25c40fb
* 9ceb4b0
* ed40e2c
>>> (main) git checkout ed40e2c
>>> (@ed40e2c) git switch -c test-rebase
>>> (test-rebase) echo "foo" >> ./test.txt
>>> (test-rebase) git commit -am "test message"
>>> (test-rebase) git push -u origin test-rebase
>>> (test-rebase) git branch -vv | grep test-rebase
* test-rebase  6c0f33e [origin/test-rebase] test message
>>> (test-rebase) // create a pr in GitHub
>>> (test-rebase) git rebase main
>>> (test-rebase ⇣1⇡5) git pull -r
>>> (test-rebase ⇡4) git push
>>> (test-rebase) // now my pr has other's commits, and I'm also the coauthor of those commits
>>> (test-rebase) git log --oneline --graph test-rebase origin/test-rebase main origin/main
* 8bd227f (HEAD -> test-rebase, origin/test-rebase) message-4
* 938935c message-3
* 4080d9d message-2
* 8dbd5cd message-1
* 6c0f33e test message
| * fa9a315 (origin/main, origin/HEAD, main) message-4
| * e52240c message-3
| * 25c40fb message-2
| * 9ceb4b0 message-1
|/  
* ed40e2c
```

Comment: I think it is better if you show us this output after all those operations: `git log --oneline --graph test-rebase origin/test-rebase main origin/main`

Comment: @eftshift0 I have updated with your advice, these commits with message like 'message-*' are other's commits. I don't know why they have new commit hash in branch test-rebase.

Comment: I provided the explanation about what is going on as an answer already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand what is going on.

So.... first, you push the branch after adding a single commit, right? And you set it as the upstream. So, you have this:

```
XXXX test message (HEAD -> test-rebase, origin/test-rebase)
ed40e2c whatever commit on that commit
```

Then, you rebase on top of `main`.... so you end up with:

```
* XXXX' test message (HEAD-> test-rebase)
* fa9a315 blahblah (main)
* e52240c blahblah
* 25c40fb blahblah
* 9ceb4b0 blahblah
| * XXXX  test message (origin/test-rebase)
|/
* ed40e2c blahblah
```

Then you run `git pull -r` and this is where you mess up because you are *rebasing* the commits that are coming from `main` that are already part of your branch *on top* of the branch that you pushed already. That's why your PR includes those commits you are talking about.

I think instead of `git pull -r` you should do `git push -f` so that you put your *just rebased on top of* `main` branch replacing the old branch for your PR.

Comment: Can you give me more detail about that `git pull -r`, I'm still a little confused about that, but `git push -f` do solve my problem, thanks!

Comment: Well, `git pull -r` tells git: _do a fetch to get the latest updates from the upstream branch... then do a rebase of current branch on top of its upstream_. So, assuming that you are the only one pushing into that branch, the upstream is _behind_... as expected, because you pushed into it before you rebased.... but then rebase checks what commits are between the upstream and your branch... and it's the last 4 commits of `main` and then your final commit... and they will _all_ be rebased on top of the original commit that you did on your branch (the current position of upstream).... BOOM!!!!